# How do I disable/remove menu item "PowerPoint Options" in PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, ribbon, office-automation

I'm trying to lock down PowerPoint and I can get rid of some of the commands by using some ribbon-customization xml and group policies. But I need to remove or disable two more options.

**PowerPoint Options** - This button shows when you click on the Office icon

This item is also available in Word (Word Options) and Excel (Excel Options), so it should be the same solution.

In Office 2003 I could remove any item I wanted by deleting objects from _pptApplication.CommandBars.

**Update:** I can now [disable Quick Access Toolbar with group policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179081.aspx). But I could not find anything there for "PowerPoint Options".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be disabled (not hidden) in PowerPoint/Office 2007 with some customUI-xml and the id "ApplicationOptionsDialog"; see http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/02/03/ribbon-step-by-step-part-3-the-office-menu-and-re-purposing.aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" enabled="false"/>
    </commands>
</customUI>
```

In PowerPoint/Office 2010 it can also be hidden; see http://www.rondebruin.nl/backstage.htm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <commands>
        <command idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" enabled="false"/>
    </commands>
    <backstage>
        <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
    </backstage>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is no "official" way to do this so I created a workaround for my (controlled) environment.

Basically I check the screen for when the "office ball" turns dark orange and then shows a topmost form exactly where the "PowerPoint options" button is.

I anyone has a better solution I would **like to know**!

Comment: that may be the scariest solution i've seen ;)